# How to disable button when service finish?

Tags: java, android, android-service

In my UpdateFragment I have a button. When I click this button it gets disabled and calls a method from service.

How can I change the button back to *enabled* from my service method?

```
/* THIS IS updateFRAGMENT */
btnUpdateApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FileUtil.logInformation(this.getClass().getName(), getResources().getText(R.string.manual_update_start).toString());

             //disable button
             btnUpdateApp.setEnabled(false);

             ServiceUtils s = new ServiceUtils();
             s.getUpdateInfos();

        }
    });


/* THIS IS MY SERVICE METHOD */
public void getUpdateInfos(){
    try {

        // ... some steps here ...

        //I want to return my button enabled here
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `getUpdateInfos` pass the reference to the button, like this:

```
s.getUpdateInfos(btnUpdateApp);
```

Make the `getUpdateInfos` method accept the new parameter:

```
public void getUpdateInfos(YourButtonType btnUpdateApp) {
```

And when you are done with your actions, use the reference to change the button back to enabled:

```
btnUpdateApp.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a listener a pass it to the service. Something like this will make the job:

```
public interface ServiceListener(){
    void onServiceFinished();
}
```

Make your fragment implement the listener and re-enable your button inside the onServiceFinished method. In your service, just call the listener's method when needed.